# Definitions of "non-degenerative closed bounded intervals"

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

What is the definition of a non-degenerative closed-bounded interval? 
An example would also be extremely helpful.

Comment: Example: $[3,3]$ is degenerate because it is only one point. $[3,8]$ is non-degenerate.

Comment: For future reference: the term is *non-degenerate*, not *non-degenerative*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Is there a difference between `[3,3]`, `[3,3)`, `(3, 3]` ? I guess not and all are degenerate.

Comment: @gotqn There is a difference between them - we have $[3,3]=\{3\}$, while $[3,3)=(3,3]=\varnothing$. However, all of them are considered degenerate.

Answer (score 0):

Any set of the form $[a,b] = \{x: a \le x \le b \}$ where $a <  b$ (the non-degenerate part), e.g. in the reals.

Comment: Is this saying that the closed interval [a,b] has established endpoints (a on the left hand side, b on the right hand side), and that the term "non-degenerate" just means that the interval does not go on forever towards either infinity or negative infinity?

Comment: @user145551 $a$ and $b$ not infinity, is the bounded part.